# How do I avoid this weird pixelated effect when creating a grunge texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes, pbr

So I was informed by one of the moderators that my post's title was not specific enough. So I decided to just create another one that aligned more with my problem and deleted the last post. Hope that's alright.

So I am trying to create the same kind of grungy type texture of this chair (the one that the girl is sitting on),[image]

and I am having some trouble. This is what I have so far in Blender:
[image]

Unfortunately, I keep getting these spots that are weirdly pixelated like this:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can get rid of that weird pixelated effect on my grunge texture???
Also, in what ways can I get my material to more closely resemble the texture of the chair in the first image?

I want to create this texture completely procedurally, and I do not want to use an image texture. Here is a copy of my [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sttvqxbukxisqbl/AABClGLGkbif3p4VXZ7PND-3a?dl=0), and down below are a few screenshots of my node setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Sorry about that! I will keep that in mind and edit next time instead of reposting. I'm not sure if my last question was put on hold or not.

Comment: It was not on hold, I just requested a clearer title, which you already provided here. Your "pixelated" effect most likely originates from poor UV map coordinates

Comment: Okay, right on. 

Well, I actually UV unwrapped it and used the project from view (bounds) option. So there isn't really any weird defects with the UV island. So I don't think it's that.

Comment: @SMH The problem was your Voronoi vector which was causing the problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that your plugging the colour output of your noise, Voronoi and white noise textures into the colour ramps and math nodes in image 2 of your node trees this can give weird results. instead you should use the outputs with the grey colour such as distance, value, fac

here is my take on the fabric using you node tree
[image]

Comment: Nah, the Voronoi's position he used as a vector destroyed the white noise. Anyways, nice attempt at an answer :)

Comment: I meant more for the noises as you can see above when plugged into the colour the result is pixelated but thanks

Comment: You are to some extent right, but the problem you are addressing in your answer is also caused by the normal map attache between the bum node. Anyways, yes, the colour makes the shading vary in procedural textures, and it has different bump values. + 1 :)

Comment: yep i see. thank you

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT, Problem Solved:**

Your Voronoi and White Noise texture destroys it. The white noise is noise, and the Voronoi vector makes it blocky. Use another mapping node or a new mapping node as a vector, and it solves the problem. I would have shown that it fixed the problem, but I changed too much of the texture, and the scale is gone all wrong :) [image]

After using a bump node, you don't connect it to a normal map to use it as a normal output, it already has a vector output. Delete the normal map node and connect the bump node directly to the normal, and it will fix the issue.